# What is meant by calling a function by its "unqualified" name?

Tags: java, function, object, this, instance

This is the text from the book ***Data Structures and Algorithms in Java*** by ***Goodrich*** from chapter one giving reasons for use of the `this` keyword.

> To allow one constructor body to invoke another constructor body. When one method of a class invokes another method of that same class on the current
> instance, **that is typically done by using the (unqualified) name of the other
> method**. But the syntax for calling a constructor is special. Java allows use of
> the keyword this to be used as a method within the body of one constructor,
> so as to invoke another constructor with a different signature.

Why does it say *unqualified* name of the other method?

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways to call a method from another method. Generally, you'll refer to its name qualified. If I've got an object `foo` and it has a method `frobnicate`, I'll do

```
foo.frobnicate();
```

Now, if I'm already inside the right instance (say, I'm calling `frobnicate` from another method on `foo`), then I use the special variable `this`.

```
this.frobnicate();
```

But Java allows us to, as a shortcut, omit `this` and simply call the method name. The following is an example of calling the method with its *unqualified name*:

```
frobnicate();
```

The `this.` is implied.

On the other hand, the point the paragraph is trying to make is that constructors are special. We don't call constructors as `foo.frobnicate()`; we just say `Foo()`. So there has to be special syntax to call a constructor from within another constructor, i.e. `this()`.